# Is it acceptable to have articles after adjectives?

Tags: articles, adjectives, word-order, coordination

I am working for a patent company and I encountered the text which is

> constructed from conductive an electrode and a layer.

I think that the writer is trying to say that 'a conductive electrode and a conductive layer.'

But is it possible to put the words in the order of 'adjective+article+noun' in that kind of context where 'too~to' or 'so~a' kinds of grammar do not exist?

I mean, can you put an adjective before an indefinite/definite article when trying to modify more than two nouns with the same adjective?

Comment: like in the example? no...

Comment: I'd probably use "..from a conductive **pair** -- an electrode and a layer."

Comment: If you put a comma between **Conductive** and **an** then you are making a list, which is fine - but you alter your meaning considerably.

Answer (score 3):

Nope.  Articles go first, always.  This may be one of the rare instances where English is consistent.

> I mean, can you put an adjective before an indefinite/definite article when trying to modify more than two nouns with the same adjective?

The right way to do that is this:

> I looked at the blue car and boat.

Or using your example:

> constructed from a conductive electrode and layer.

For clarity, don't be afraid to repeat the adjective and/or the article - they can be omitted if it's clear the adjective/article applies to both nouns.  When in doubt, repeat them.

> constructed from a conductive electrode and conductive layer
>
> constructed from a conductive electrode and a conductive layer

Or you can use the word *both*:

> constructed from both a conductive electrode and layer

Comment: I really appreciate your kind reply. It helped a lot. :)

Comment: Adjective phrases also appear in predeterminer function, *before* an article.